# How to specify one optional argument several times in docopt

Tags: python, docopt

I'd like to design my command line application in a way that one option, let's call it *comment*, can be specified several times, e.g.,

```
$ ./my_app.py --comment="Comment 1" --comment="Comment 2"
```

Can this be done with docopt? I checked the docopt homepage but couldn't find any reference to multiple occurences of the same optional argument.

Comment: I'm not sure about docopt, but with argparse you can do it using [append action](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, the official docs can be [found here at github](https://github.com/docopt/docopt).

To answer your specific question, you can use an ellipse `...` with your optional option `[--my-option]` and specify that your option takes an argument.

I.e. `[--my-option=ARG]...` or `[--my-option=<arg>]...`

Example:

```
"""
Usage:
    my_program [--comment=ARG]... FILE

Arguments:
    FILE       An argument for passing in a file.

Options:
    --comment  Zero or more comments
"""
```

By specifying it as `[--comment=<arg>]...` you ensure that opt['--comment'] is a list of all the specified comments.

Executing: `my_program --comment=ASDF --comment=QWERTY my_file`

Leads to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    opts = docopt(__doc__)
    opts['--comment'] == ['ASDF', 'QWERTY']
    opts['FILE'] == 'my_file'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `...` to indicate a repeating element and `[ ]` to indicate that it is optional:

```
my_program [comment]...
```

This indicates `comment` is optional and can be repeated.

Comment: But omits the `--comment` part: In my case, I have other required positional arguments, and this would be hard to discern, and potentially ambiguous. (e.g., I'd like `./myprog.py --comment "ASDF" --comment "QWERTY" my_file`)